# Magen Avraham's sources from the Arizal

Tags: commentaries, mesorah-tradition, arizal

When the Magen Avraham (commentary on Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim) refers to כתבים, writings, as his source, I take it for granted that he is referring to the writings of the students of the Arizal. Which exact sources where available to him, and are they primary or secondary sources?

While this is a general question about dozens of references throughout the Magen Avraham, I was spurred to ask based upon his comment on [111:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.111.2?lang=bi&with=Magen%20Avraham&lang2=en):

> החזן כשמתחיל י"ח בקול רם חוזר ואומר ה' שפתי תפתח ופי יגיד וכו':
>
> The leader of the prayer, when beginning the recitation of the Amidah out loud, repeats [the first verse] and says: "God, open my lips and my mouth shall praise, etc."

Where he writes:

> חוזר ואומר כו'. בלחש ה' שפתי [כתבים]
>
> He goes back and says...: quietly "Hashem, open my mouth" (writings)

And on this the [Kaf Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.111.2?lang=bi&with=Kaf%20HaChayim&lang2=en) writes:

> אומרו בקול רם וכ"מ מדברי שער הכוו'... משמע דאין חילוק דאפי' פסוק אדני שפתי וכו' אומרים אותו בקול רם, ומ"ש המ"א סק"ג בשם הכתבים דהחזן חוזר ואומר בלחש ה' שפתי אפשר שהוא משאר כתבי תלמידי האר"י ז"ל אשר לא סמך ידו עליהם,
>
> It is said aloud, and so is implied from the Shar Hakavanos (primary source for expositions of the Arizal)... This implies that there is no distinction, and even the verse "Hashem, open my mouth..." is said aloud. And what the Magen Avraham #3 writes in the name of the writings, that the chazan goes back and says quietly "Hashem, open my mouth...", perhaps it is from other writings of students of the Arizal that he (the Arizal) did not endorse.

Comment: The Marchon Yerushalayim Shulchan Aruch cites all the sources for the Magen Avraham. The few I've checked out were pri eitz Chaim or eitz Chaim.

Comment: My question is more about which editions were available to him, as the exact wording is often of great interest, and I would like to be able to know if his sources can be superseded by (i.e. corrected based upon) better editions.

Comment: Are you familiar with Kitvei HaAri and its editions to ask this question?

Comment: When the Kaf HaChaim refers to the writings of "other students" of the Ari z'l that he didn't authorize, he is most likely referring to teachings of Rabbi Yisrael Serug who brought many of the teachings of the Ari z'l to Europe via Italy and Rabbi Menachem Azarya of Fano. There was also a channel of teachings that came via Rabbi Moshe Alshich who was the teacher of Rabbi Chaim Vital prior to his meeting the Ari z'l.

Comment: @MDjava, I know that Eitz Chaim is supposed to be directly from Rav Chaim Vital and the the Shmone Sharim was edited by his son Rav Shmuel Vital. Pri Eitz Chaim was edited by Yaakov Tzemach, a student of Rav Shmuel, and he also wrote Nagid Umitzaveh. I don't know how these works would have made their way to the Magen Avraham, or if perhaps other editions or anthologies exist that he would have seen.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that, although not a student of the Ari z'l, the Magen Avraham was also familiar with the kabbalistic teachings of Rabbi Shlomo Molcho, HY'D.